# bone bigger than armature

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, rigify

I'm trying out my first rig with rigify. But the bone is always larger than the armature.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the dimensions are different and if the dimensions are matched, the camera perspective changes.

How can i have the bone size same as the armature?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to select your Meta-Rig and go into Edit Mode - select all the bones and scale to your Mesh size. You could also do the same thing in Object mode, with one additional step - applying the scale with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

This answers your question - below is just extra stuff that may be helpful...

The scale should by default go towards the Median point - which is that little orange dot which identifies the root of your object. At the moment your Mesh object and Meta-Rig object have different positions for the Median point. Best practice is to get them aligned. You can do this by selecting your Meta-Rig in Object mode and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to Selected. With the position established now select your Mesh in Object mode and move the Median point to the same location...

[image: Set Origin]

Now you can return to your Meta-Rig in Edit mode and start positioning the bones...